# write serial command benq projector

Tags: serial

I have a problem.
I have a BenQ projector with a serial connection.

when I send a command with minicom, my project going on or off.
I send: *POW=OFF#

in the manuaal is de command: *pow=on# (ASCII)

when I use phyton nothing happens.
I have this script in it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
baudrate = 115200,
parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
timeout=5
)

ser.write(b'<CR>*POW=OFF#<CR>')
ser.close()
```

I run this like this in the terminal: sudo python serial_write.py
this is not working and I am not getting an error message.
I have also tried without

Comment: For a start you are not sending the command you say the manual needs.

Comment: what do you mean?  can you explain it?